# What is the correct regular expression for mobile number

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to have a regular expression that only allows a mobile number entered starting with a 0 then follows with 10 more digits (0 to 9) for example:

01234567899
07777777777
02345467890

i have this so far but lets me typed more than 10 extra digits

i am using vs2013 ultimate in mvc4 application c#

```
 [RegularExpression("^0[0-9\\d{10}]+$", ErrorMessage="Must begin with a 0, followed by ten digits")]
    public string clientMobileNo { get; set; }
```

any help would be apprieciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have this so far but lets me typed more than 10 extra digits

Because your regex is incorrect.  Use:

```
^0\\d{10}$
```

Anything within `[...]` is considered to be a character class.  You are matching anything starting with `0`, and containing 1 or more of `0-9\\d{10}`.  Your regex would even accept `{` and `}`!

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression should be:

```
^0[0-9]{10}$
```